# Return multiple values from (while) loop javascript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I can't wrap my head around a piece of code using loops and functions in javascript.
I have a function which generates random numbers (between a min and max), see below:

```
const getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 
}
```

Below a simple Function which returns true if 2 random numbers add up to 10, else it returns false:

```
const Function1 = (n1, n2) => (n1 + n2 === 10) ? true : false
```

Below i will use Function1 to return n1 and n2:

```
const Function1Check= () => {
    const n1 = getRandomNumber(-10, 10);
    const n2 = getRandomNumber(-10, 10);
    if(Function1(n1, n2)) {
     return [n1, n2]
    } else {
     return {false}
   }
}


const LoopFunction = () => {
    while(Function1Check === false) {
       Function1Check();
     if(Function1Check) {break;}
  }
}
```

My while loop does not work correctly, what am i missing?
Hope you guys can help me out and point me in the right direction using vanilla javascript.
Thanks in advance.

Greetings.

Comment: *"I have tried different things with while loops..."* That's the kind of thing you'd want to do, show us that.

Comment: `while` loop doesn't return anything, please show your loop, and be specific when describing the problem.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. It will help us understand the problem better and help you.

Comment: notice how low probable is that you get the right numbers,maybe your freezing is because of that

Comment: before your last edit, you wanted a loop with 5 results. Now you only want one. But that's still roughly 0.22% probable. You should expect to wait for a while (pun not intended)

Comment: I did edit the code a bit too fast. But i got what i was looking for. THanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a do.. while loop and quit after a maximum number of attempts to avoid an infinite loop.

The loop will also terminate once the target length of the array is reached:

```js
const getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; // max & min both included 
}

const Function1 = (n1, n2) => (n1 + n2 === 10) ? true : false

const Function1Check = () => {
    const n1 = getRandomNumber(-10, 10);
    const n2 = getRandomNumber(-10, 10);
    if(Function1(n1, n2)) {
        return [n1, n2]
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


let rightNumbers = [];
let attempts = 0;
let maxAttempts = 1000;
let target = 5;

do {
   let numbers = Function1Check();
   if (numbers) {
       rightNumbers.push(numbers);
   }
} while (rightNumbers.length < target && (attempts++) < maxAttempts)

console.log(`Found ${target} number(s) after ${attempts} attempts`);
console.log(`Numbers:`, rightNumbers)
```

Comment: nice addition of `maxAttempts`

Comment: perfect, this is what i was looking for!!

Comment: (after your edit) please notice that is not the same generating two random numbers and checking if they fulfill a given constraint than generating one random number and forcing the other to comply with the constraint

Comment: Oh, yes I agree I'm probably missing something. It's just a possible approach, perhaps suitable for a similar issue. I'll delete the second snippet if you feel it adds nothing!

Comment: I hadn't see the update at that point.. I've updated again.

Answer (score 2):

If your program freezes that's a clear sign that your while loop doesn't stop.

I'd approach it the following way:

```js
const AMOUNT_OF_RESULTS = 5;
const results = [];

// This would be the correct predicate to stop your while loop. 
// You want to stop looping once you have 5 correct results.
while (results.length < AMOUNT_OF_RESULTS ) {
    const result = checkRightNumbers();

    // If result is not false(an array in your case)
    if(!result) {
        // Then add the result to the array of results:
        results.push(result);
    }
}
```

The loop will continue generating results until it filled the quota(AMOUNT_OF_RESULTS).

Answer (score 1):

A method which achieves what you are trying to do looks something like this:

```
const getSolutionSet = () => {
  let answers = [];

  while(answers.length < 5){
    let check = checkRightNumbers(); 
    if(check){
      answers.push(check);
    }
  }

  return answers;
}
```

You could make it a bit more advanced, by passing the amount of results as a parameter

```
const getSolutionSet = (numResults) => {
  let answers = [];

  while(answers.length < numResults){
    let check = checkRightNumbers(); 
    if(check){
      answers.push(check);
    }
  }

  return answers;
}
```

You should keep in mind, that the probability is pretty low to find an exact match, so adding a max number of tries would also be a good idea

Comment: using maxAttempts stopped my screen from freezing. THanks